# Why did Daniel Jackson reopen the Abydos Stargate?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

Recently I was rewatching Stargate: SG-1 and a question occurred to me: Canonically, why did Daniel Jackson unblock the Abydos stargate?

> Kawalsky: What's going on, Daniel? Could it be another Ra?
> Daniel: How should I know? I should've left the barricade up. This is my fault.

Unblocking the Abydos gate precipitated the events of the entire series. Though as far as I'm aware, the Abydonians have no use for it. They're not shown conducting trade, and trade in the Milky Way is facilitated through the Goa'uld. Having recently liberated themselves, I doubt they'd have any desire to reach out.

Jackson's discovery of the cartouche lead him to deduce the existence of other gates, perhaps he wanted to test that theory?

Comment: He ran out of tissue paper? ;) I have wondered that myself.

Comment: IIRC, he found a "map" room that had additional addresses to other worlds.

Comment: @agarza Yes, that's the cartouche. The question is whether the actual reason is ever stated.

Comment: @Questor LOL, I was going to post the same comment. :D

Comment: @BMF [Valorum's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/280880/130762) is what I was alluding to.

Comment: @agarza I know what you were alluding to because I alluded to the exact same in [my question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/280857/112822). Valorum confirmed my suspicions though with concrete evidence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Daniel found a room with multiple gate addresses. He was conducting his own experiments to see if any of them led elsewhere. This necessitated him uncovering the Stargate.

> But even more amazing than the wadjet-eye were the lines upon lines of
> carvings that occupied the walls of the room, floor to ceiling,
> between the obelisks. The towering stones too were covered with
> symbols. Unlike the eye of Horus, **the symbols covering the rest of the
> room were not Egyptian, but combinations, variations, and permutations
> of the symbols on the Stargates.**
>
> ...
>
> “Because after Colonel O’Neill and his team came back,” she explained,
> **“my team tried hundreds of symbol permutations, using Earth as the
> point of origin, and it never worked.”**
>
> Daniel nodded eagerly. **“I tried the same here,** but it didn’t work
> either. I figured the destinations I tried are destroyed or buried.
> But some of them somewhere must still exist.”
>
> Carter shook her head. “I don’t think so.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Stargate: SG-1 - Official Novelisation](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Stargate_SG-1_(novel))</sup></sub>

Comment: Ah, I think that definitively answers it! I'll wait the customary 24 hours to accept. I think it was a little reckless, him knowing that aliens immitated gods, but then iirc later on in the episode he makes the realization out loud.

Comment: @BMF - He was, presumably, also going to share the info with Earth if he found anything useful.